# React using react-router-dom shows nothing on screen

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

No error message but it just shows a white screen nothing more. These 3 components matter, the other ones are just unedited snippets (ES6 rafce). The only error I got was useHistory imported but not used, but this one mysteriously disappeared upon restarting the app (npm start). I did change the index a bit before restarting however, but that was just changing component in the Route to element as you can see below.

Edit (because of duplicate question): I know that this route in the index to route the root to app is kind of weird but I tried importing routes as well and enclosing it in it, as well as just using the `<App />` directly. Both still gave a white a screen. I think it probably has  something to do with the navbar because I was working on it when this problem first occured. However I first added the Links in the navbar only after I added the routes to App and the BrowserRouter to index. So there could be something wrong there as well.

Index component

```
//index.js

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
      <Route path="/" element={<App />} />
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

App component

```
//App.js

import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import Footer from './components/Footer';
import Home from './components/Home';
import AboutUs from './components/AboutUs';
import Contact from './components/Contact';
import Missing from './components/Missing';
import { Route, Routes, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar />
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <Home />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/contact">
          <Contact />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/about_us" element={<AboutUs />} />
        <Route path="*" element={<Missing />} />
      </Routes>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Navbar component

```
//Navbar.js

import React from 'react';
import logo from "../images/Odanhu1.png";
import { FaInstagram, FaUser } from 'react-icons/fa';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    <nav>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li><Link to="/">
            <figure>
              <img src={logo} alt="logo" />
              <figcaption>danhu</figcaption>
            </figure>
          </Link></li>
          <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/"><FaInstagram /></a></li>
          <li><Link to="/about_us">About us</Link></li>
          <li><Link to="/contact">Contact</Link></li>
          <li><p>Partners</p></li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
          <li><Link><FaUser /></Link></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p></p>
      </div>
    </nav>
  )
}

export default Navbar
```

Comment: I think you can't have a Route without being wrapped in Routes (in your index.js) and I don't think this route alone is usefull, Just render directly your App

Comment: The `"/"` route rendering `App` is pretty useless, just render `App` directly and let it render the navbar and app routes. The issue there is addressed by the marked duplicate. If you ***really*** want to keep the root route rendering `App` then append `"*"` to the path so descendent routes can be matched, e.g. `<Route path="/*" element={<App />} />`. Remove the `useHistory` import.

Comment: The duplicate explains the white page. It's not the navbar, it's the `"/"` and `"/contact"` routes missing an `element` prop.

Comment: @DrewReese I edited it as you suggested and it still shows a white page. Before both elements were enclosed in Route is this also no longer correct to do?

Comment: Correct. Render the routed content on the `element` prop. `Route` components can only wrap other `Route` components in the case of building nested routing. If you are struggling to get the routing/rendering working could you create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of your code that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: @DrewReese I created a sandbox with the changes you up until now suggested "Anonymous / gifted-marco-klj9pq". First time I use this so I hope this is enough information. I did not know how to import an image however, hope this isn't a problem.

Comment: You can likely skip images, we just need to see the routing and components. In the upper-right corner there should be a "share" button that you can copy the sandbox link of. Be sure to save all your changes.

Comment: @DrewReese

<iframe src="https://codesandbox.io/embed/gifted-marco-klj9pq?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark"
     style="width:100%; height:500px; border:0; border-radius: 4px; overflow:hidden;"
     title="gifted-marco-klj9pq"
     allow="accelerometer; ambient-light-sensor; camera; encrypted-media; geolocation; gyroscope; hid; microphone; midi; payment; usb; vr; xr-spatial-tracking"
     sandbox="allow-forms allow-modals allow-popups allow-presentation allow-same-origin allow-scripts"
   ></iframe>

https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-marco-klj9pq?from-embed

Comment: Your routes are rendering just fine once you import all the dependencies and resolve the one link missing a `to` prop. https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-pond-83h92n?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @DrewReese well you commented out the one Link around FaUser, which solved the problem. Thanks a lot for that!! The problem was in the navbar after all. Could you submit this as an answer so I can happily accept it?

Comment: Split the difference and count that one as a freebie since your original post subject was about blank pages which was more related to the routes? 

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to wrap your App component in a `<route>` when you render it.

Try this:

```
//index.js

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
//you don't need to routes in index and the app file

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
        <App/>
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Comment: That doesn't work. It still shows a white screen. This came directly from a tutorial video and it worked perfectly fine for the guy. It more than a year old tho so I treid your suggestion anyways and it didn't resolve the problem as said I before.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the tutorial video?

Comment: @JalenWithTheHead Is that really relevant here? Lots of RRD tutorials became outdated over the last year when RRDv6 arrived and they didn't update to remain relevant with current RRD versions.

Comment: @JalenWithTheHead https://youtu.be/RVFAyFWO4go learn react by Dave Grey, chapter 17 and 18.

Comment: @DrewReese I understand that. Being able to see the tutorial would allow me to see what he was talking about. You're right though, the duplicates and missing element prop are causing the blank screen.

Comment: @JalenWithTheHead could you explain what you mean by the duplicates?

Comment: You don't need to have your app component wrapped in a <Route> in your index.js file. Just render it. I updated my answer

Comment: @JalenWithTheHead I did like mentioned in the edit.

I now have:
<React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
      <App />
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>